# Golang function call on template fails on a single struct

Tags: go

i have following code

```
func (w *Warehouse) GetId() string {
  return w.Id.Hex()
}
```

view multiple works perfect

```
{{ range .Data }}
   <tr>
   <td>{{ .Name }}</td>
   <td>{{ .City }}</td>
   <td>{{ .Manager }}</td>
   <td><a class="blue" href="/warehouse/show/{{ .GetId }}">view</a></td>
   </tr>
{{ end }}
```

in single show warehouse i do this but that fails while .Data.Name return the name correctly

```
{{ .Data.GetId }}
```

any idea what i am missing here?

Comment: If you range on .Data, I guess it's an array, not a struct.

Comment: Dont you need to run `.GetId` as a function? So: `.GetId()`. Or am I misunderstanding the templates you're working with?

Comment: in the top example is .Data an array of structs, in the bottom one its a single struct.

Answer (score 1):

problem is that i needed to make instance of my struct like this

```
var warehouse = new(models.Warehouse) // works
```

instead of

```
var warehouse models.Warehouse // fails
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code .Data is array or slice. It does not have GetId() method